# Google Maps API returns 'undefined' when I try to remove a marker?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Using the Google Maps v3 API, I cant understand why I get '`undefined`' as the result of the below code when I am simply trying to remove a marker from a map?

Problem Example from Firebug Console:

```
>>> map
Object { gm_accessors_={...}, zoom=9, more...}
>>> markersList[1].visible
true
>>> markersList[1].setMap(null)
undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that markersList is an array of Google Maps Marker instances.  When you invoke setMap(null) on a marker, the return value is undefined, just as you see it.  You should also see the marker is now removed from your map page.  You can see the same thing if you go to http://www.ecu.edu/campusmaps and use the console to reference myMarkers.  Take myMarkers[0].setMap(null) and you'll see the result is undefined.  Most importantly, you'll see that the [Google Maps API reference for the Marker class](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker) shows a return value of "None".

Comment: Thanks ---- its late friday afternoon...i way way over thought about that problem...........thanks for sharing the clarity!